# How to validate DMN model in Drools in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: spring-boot, validation, visual-studio-code, drools, dmn

I have DMN file created within drools in VSC. I like to validate the DMN file within VCS and check if all syntax, rules defined are valid or not. I know at compile time, in VSC the feature is not yet available but is there any other option to validate DMN model ? I have seen the plugin dmn-check available for the validation. Any other option is still available ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only option for DMN Validation is via the maven plugin while building Spring Boot (or Quarkus) Kogito application.

We are still planning on how to provide such a feature directly to our DMN editor. Stay tuned.